# Composition of gradients

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory

Gradient vector fields are quite useful in many applications. They however do not generate a Lie Algebra, especially because composition of gradient does not give a gradient. I know that a differentiable vector field $X:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a gradient if and only if its Jacobian is symmetric.

This means that the family of gradient fields is quite small. I've seen results about classifying the vector fields that can be approximated arbitrarily well by a gradient vector field on a compact set.

My questions are then three:

- Are there results about what classes of functions can be exactly represented by composing two gradients? i.e. what are the properties of $X:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ in order for it to satisfy $X(x) = \nabla f\circ \nabla g(x)$ for every $x\in E$, $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ compact, for some $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?
- What if the requirement is relaxed to finding those $X$s that for a fixed $\varepsilon>0$ satisfy $\max_{x\in E}\|X(x) - \nabla f\circ \nabla g(x)\|<\varepsilon$?
- If any of the two results above are investigated somewhere, is also the extension to more compositions studied? Like $\nabla f\circ\nabla g\circ\nabla h(x)$?

It might be that this problem has never been considered because of not much interest, but I think it is mathematically interesting and this is why I'm asking this. The approximation "power" given by function compositions is very surprising many times, so I expect that already with two compositions the approximable space increases quite considerably.

Comment: It is well-known that $\mathbb R^3$ becomes a Lie algebra with the usual cross product. Every vector $(x,y,z)$ is a gradient, namely of the function $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}\,.$ Therefore I find your second sentence very confusing. You should give some motivations of your very peculiar definition of a Lie algebra.

Comment: What I mean is that if you take two arbitrary differentiable functions $f,g$, even on $\mathbb{R}^3$, then the Jacobi-Lie bracket $[\nabla f,\nabla g](x)$ is not a gradient in general. This is because $\nabla f(\nabla g(x))$ is not a gradient. So what is not a Lie Algebra is the set $\{\nabla f : f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})\}$

Comment: Still quite confusing. I know the [Lie bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields) of two vector fields $X,Y$ as their commutator applied to a scalar function $f\,.$ You seem to have two vector valued (?) functions $f,g$ and take the commutator of their Jacobian matrices ? Or what is that when $f,g$ are scalar valued and $\nabla f,\nabla g$ are ordinary gradients ? Seems like you define it as $\nabla f\circ \nabla g-\nabla g\circ \nabla f\,.$ If so: that's where the peculiarites begin in my opinion. What is the motivation?

Comment: A reason why this is peculiar is that a bracket $[X,Y]$ is usually linear in $X$ and $Y\,.$

Comment: So $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are scalar valued. So the commutator is exactly the one you define $[\nabla f,\nabla g](x) = \nabla f(\nabla g(x))-\nabla g(\nabla f(x))$. My motivation would be to try to characterize the space of vector valued functions $\mathcal{F}=\{F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n\}$ that can be either represented or approximated by compositions of gradients, i.e. by vector valued functions of the form $\nabla f(\nabla g) : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: In my case the vector fields involved are gradients, this is the only difference from the generic case. However the set of all vector valued functions $X:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lie-Algebra with respect to that commutator, while if you restrict to only gradient it is not anymore

Comment: Your "commutator" $\nabla f\circ \nabla g-\nabla g\circ \nabla f$ is not linear. This rules out talking about Lie algebras. Maybe $\nabla f(\nabla g)$ is not a gradient in the original coordinates but it could be one in new coordinates under the transformation $\nabla g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ when that is sufficiently bijective. I leave that to you.